# nginx location regex not working

Tags: nginx, regex, regular-expressions

I'm trying to setup location directive to match my request but can't get it working.

Below is my sample request:

/APP/public/api/v1/item/100/type

```
location ~* ^/APP/public/api/v1/item/(.*)/type {                
    try_files /APP/data/type/$1.json @apache;   
}
```

If I set like below it works:

```
location = ^/APP/public/api/v1/item/100/type {              
   try_files /APP/data/type/100.json @apache;   
}
```

Am I missing anything ? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this causes your issue, but your regular expression isn't optimal. `location ~* ^/APP/public/api/v1/item/([0-9]+)/type$ {` allows only numbers one or more times and makes sure there can't be anything extra after the "type" suffix.

Comment: Second example couldn't match anything. Either it's a typo or your request is processed within some other location.

Answer (score 0):

Try just setting up the context for request processing, and then use a rewrite rule inside of that context, something like:

```
location ~ ^/APP/public/api/v1/item/ {
  rewrite ^/APP/public/api/v1/item/([0-9]+)/type /APP/data/type/$1.json break;
  try_files $uri @apache;
}
```

Comment: What is your source for the "doesn't create match groups" statement? I've used regular expression match groups in `location` directives succesfully in many occasions.

Comment: Sure, just sloppy writing, there are issues using match groups (proxy_pass, etc). Will edit.